# Bootstrap input-group-addon is not clickable using bootstrap studio

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I follow [this site](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=component&format=yyyy-mm-dd&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=pl&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox)

which generated html:

```
    <div class="input-group date">
          <input type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
    </div>
```

and .js

```
    $('#sandbox-container .input-group.date').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        language: "pl"
    });
```

I have the same html and .js it looks oke but the input-group-addon is not clickable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('.input-group.date').datepicker({
  format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
  language: "pl"
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group date">
  <input type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

What is`#sandbox-container`?

Hope this will help you.